# core data: change objects in NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification

Tags: core-data

Is it possible to change attributes of managed objects in NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification handler without firing the handler again?
I get the data from our server and RestKit maps the data into Core Data. I have to change some attributes after the data arrives in my database.
Thanks for help.

Edit:
This is my code. The `handleDidChangeNotification`method is called in a cycle:

```
- (void)addMyObserver
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleDidChangeNotification:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
}

- (void)handleDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSSet *updatedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *deletedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *insertedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];

    // modifiedObjects with store entity:
    NSSet *modifiedObjects = [updatedObjects setByAddingObjectsFromSet:insertedObjects];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF isKindOfClass: %@", [MyStore class]];
    NSSet *modifiedStoreObjects = [modifiedObjects filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if (modifiedStoreObjects.count > 0)
    {
        [modifiedStoreObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MyStore *store, BOOL *stop)
         {
             store.distanceValue = 1000;
         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a separate MOC for the import? That way you could observe just that context to make this change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify a Core Data object without firing the change notifications, you can use the
*primitive accessor methods*, e.g.

```
[store setPrimitiveValue:@1000 forKey:@"distanceValue"];
```

(Note that an object value is required here, a scalar value does not work.)

But you should consider carefully if there are not any unwanted side effects, because
other listeners will also *not* be notified about the changed value.

Another possible solution might be to check if the attribute has to be changed at all,
and modify only if necessary.

Comment: I heard about this, but I think it's not recommended in this case and you may have side effects, as you mentioned. I think, I will do the distance update manually after I retrieve the response of my data request. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Does this break undo?

Comment: @malhal: I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is off the top of my head, not tested, but this is how I would go.

```
@interface MyStoreCoordinator () {
    bool _changingValue;
}
@end

@implementation MyStoreCoordinator

- (void)addMyObserver
{
    _changingValue = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleDidChangeNotification:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
}

- (void)handleDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (_changingValue)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSSet *updatedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *deletedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *insertedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];

    // modifiedObjects with store entity:
    NSSet *modifiedObjects = [updatedObjects setByAddingObjectsFromSet:insertedObjects];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF isKindOfClass: %@", [MyStore class]];
    NSSet *modifiedStoreObjects = [modifiedObjects filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if (modifiedStoreObjects.count > 0)
    {
        [modifiedStoreObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MyStore *store, BOOL *stop)
         {
             _changingValue = YES;
             store.distanceValue = 1000;
             _changingValue = NO;
         }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example how to should look subclass of `NSManagedObject`. `YourPropertyName` - is your class

```
@implementation YourPropertyName

@dynamic stringValueOfYourProperty;//for example

-(void)setStringValueOfYourProperty:(NSString *) _stringValueOfYourProperty
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"stringValueOfYourProperty"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue: _stringValueOfYourProperty forKey:@"stringValueOfYourProperty"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"stringValueOfYourProperty"];
}
```

Then just use `setStringValueOfYourProperty` anywhere in code.

Comment: But `didChangeValueForKey` will fire the change notification again, that's what OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: Without `didChangeValueForKey` you can not get a side effect, if the application is multi-user?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I successfully use is (I haven't notice side effects yet. Please let me know if I'm wrong).

1. In the `didChange` CoreData notification callback, I save in a global array all the updated objects.
2. In the `willSave` CordData notification callback, I modify the object saved at point 1
3. The `didChange` callback will be called again and the `willSave` will be automatically skipped
4. `didSave` CoreData notification callback if you want!!